# How to escape " with enabledelayedexpansion in batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

Writing a simple script to find and replace a character in batch.my script contains " character which i want to replace it with some text like ".Please let me which escape character would help .Tried "" and ^" it did not work 
Script : 
`

```
    @echo off &setlocal 
    set search2="""
    set "replace2=&quot;"
    set "textfile=D:\Users\manajosh\Desktop\try-Copy.xml"
    set "newfile=D:\Users\manajosh\Desktop\Output.txt"
    (for /f "delims=" %%i in (%textfile%) do (
        set "line=%%i"
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
            set "line=!line:%search2%=%replace2%!"
            echo(!line!
        endlocal
    ))>"%newfile%"

pause 6
```

`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this technique:

```
@echo off
set "search2=""
rem  set search2="""
set "replace2=&quot;"
set "line="quoted""
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
 for /f "usebackq tokens=1,2 delims=§" %%a in ('"!search2!"§"!replace2!"') do echo "!line:%%~a=%%~b!"
endlocal
```

the thing is you need delayed expansion for line and also the search2 and replace2 - and this can be achieved with wrapping for loop.

Comment: Thanks npocmaka for the solution

Comment: Can you some suggest some way to handle !